# Can't update an updatable package

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, updates

Can anyone make sense of this?

```bsh
~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
libodbc1/buster 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.7]
libodbc1/now 2.3.7 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.3.7]
libodbc1/groovy 2.3.6-0.1build1 amd64

~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I initially thought it was an error in the repository, but it's been like this for days.

Here's some Ubuntu version info:

```bsh
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Comment: Do you have buster sources? `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` please.

Comment: I ran the command, but the output is too large to post. What should I be looking for?

Comment: You post it in your question (not in comments). In your question you have plenty of room to show the entire output that @nobody asked for.